# listener and visitor ANTLRworks 2

Tags: antlrworks, antlr4

I dont know how to make visitor and listener to work via ANTLRworks 2, I managed to create them, but do I need to write code via cmd or can I use them directly through ANTLRworks 2?

Answer (score 0):

ANTLRWorks 2 is currently designed as an IDE for ANTLR grammars themselves. The generated visitors and listeners, along with any implementation(s) of them, would be developed as part of a separate project in the target language (currently Java and C# are supported).

If you have ANTLRWorks 2 installed as a plugin for NetBeans (as opposed to the alone application), you can work with ANTLR 4 grammars directly within the context of a Java project, which may better fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I already use it that way, but even if I create visitor and listeners through I cant use them while I run my grammar.